# How to control echo reply source IP in suse linux 

Tags: linux, echo

The Client, running Suse 10. The Server, also running Suse10, and  is a Cluster with a float IP. Now there is a problem about the echo communication:

**Client send echo request server's float IP, and The Server reply to the Client with th source IP as its physical IP.  and Firewall bock the relpy because the source IP changed.**

I need the Server reply echo with its source IP as float IP. How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Then you have some seriously strange configuration. IP stacks typically send replies with the exact same source IP as the IP the original package was targeted at. Else you will not be able to have any IP communication at all, as the communication partner can not match the connection.

You probably have some loadbalancing solution which adapts IP packages (like LVM). These can be rather delicate to configure. But on your sparse information, we can not really decide what's wrong.

Comment: thanks you relpy. The server side is installing veritas cluster server. so there are float ip and its physical IP. When server sending relpy, it use the physical IP as source IP.